# javascript element body.onclick attatch event setTimeout

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, settimeout

I want to make popup div that disappears when i click outside of it. I need pure js, not a jQuery or something.
So i do the following...

function that make div to dissapear:

```
function closePopUps(){
    if(document.getElementById('contact-details-div'))
        document.getElementById('contact-details-div').style.display = 'none';
    //...same code further...
} 
function closePopUpsBody(e){
    //finding current target - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    //is we inside div?    
    while (targ.parentNode) {
        //filtering "Close" button inside div
        if (targ.className && targ.className == 'closebtn')
            break;
        if (targ.className && targ.className == 'contact-profile-popup')
            break;
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    }
    //if it not a div, or close button, hide all divs and remove event handler
    if ((targ.className && targ.className == 'closebtn')
        || !(targ.className && targ.className == 'contact-profile-popup')) {
        if(document.getElementById('contact-details-div'))
            document.getElementById('contact-details-div').style.display = 'none';
        //...some more code here...

        document.body.onclick = null;
    }
}
```

maybe this code is ugly, but this not a main problem...

main problem is when i attach an event to body, it executes immediately! and div dissapears immediately, i even don't see it.

```
<tr onclick="
closePopUps();
document.getElementById('contact-details-div').style.display='block';
document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody;
return false;">
```

i though if i don't use parentheses, it will not executes?

```
document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody(); //this executes
document.body.onclick = function(){closePopUpsBody()}; //this is not
document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody; //this is not
```

finally i finished with this decision

```
<tr onclick="
closePopUps();
document.getElementById('contact-details-div').style.display='block';
setTimeout('document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody;', 500);
return false;">
```

but i think this is madness. so, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give a link to a live example, or even better, a jsfiddle? `document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody` should work as expected.

Comment: When you have `document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody` what exactly happening when you click? You get some error?

Comment: thanks for answers, you all were right - problem in absence of stopPropagation in tr inline onclick code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop event bubbling. **Simple [[demo](http://jsbin.com/eheda5/2)]**

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var close = document.getElementById('close');

// click on a box does nothing
box.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation)
    e.stopPropagation();
}

// click everywhere else closes the box
function close_box() {
  if (box) box.style.display = "none";
}

close.onclick = document.onclick = close_box;
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually events are propagated to the parents. If you click on a `<div>`, then `<body>` also will have its onClick called.

The first thing is: debug the order of called functions: place `window.dump("I am called!")` kind of things in your handlers.

I suppose you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` somewhere in your code. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event )

About the parentheses question:

```
document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody;//this is not
document.body.onclick = closePopUpsBody();//this executes
```

This executes, because you are calling a function closePopUpsBody() to return a value which will be assigned to the onclick property. In JavaScript the function name represents the function object (as any other variable). If you place parentheses after a variable name, then you say: 'execute it for me, as a function`.

Answer (score 1):

Here 's a full example of how you could accomplish that.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body { font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 1.1em; background: #666666; color: White; }
        #layer01 { border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 100px; position: absolute; 
                   top: 100px; left: 100px; background: white; padding: 10px; color: Black;
                   display: block; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Click anywhere outside the layer to hide it.

    <div id="layer01"> Test Layer </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        isIE = (window.ActiveXObject) ? true : false;

        document.onclick = function (e) {
            var l = document.getElementById("layer01");

            if (!isIE && e.originalTarget == l)
                e.stopPropagation();
            else if (isIE && event.srcElement == l)
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            else 
                l.style.display = "none";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```